# Grails domain.list() does not retrieve data

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, grails

Using IntelliJ and Grails, I have created a database connection to my MySQL database. The connection works: I can actually see the data in IntelliJ itself when I type a query. However, when I create a domain class for the very same table and call the Wallpaper.list() method, no data is returned.

My guess is that the error is in the Domain class itself, but I cannot find a good example on the Internet as to how to create a domain class.

The domain class:

```
import grails.util.Environment

class Wallpaper {
    String location, description, purity
    Integer width, height, favourite, highQuality
    Date dateAdded

    static mapping = {
        if (Environment.current != Environment.TEST) {
            table name: 'wallpaper'
            id column: 'id', sqlType: 'NUMBER', generator: 'assigned', length: 11
        }

        location    column: 'location',     sqlType: 'VARCHAR', length: 255
        description column: 'description',  sqlType: 'VARCHAR', length: 255
        purity      column: 'purity',       sqlType: 'VARCHAR', length: 255
        width       column: 'width',        sqlType: 'NUMBER', length: 11
        height      column: 'height',       sqlType: 'NUMBER', length: 11
        favourite   column: 'favourite',    sqlType: 'NUMBER', length: 1
        highQuality column: 'high_quality', sqlType: 'NUMBER', length: 1
        dateAdded   column: 'date_added',   sqlType: 'DATE'

        version(false)
    }

    static constraints = {
        location    nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 255
        description nullable: true,  blank: false, maxSize: 255
        purity      nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 255
        width       nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 11
        height      nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 11
        favourite   nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 1
        highQuality nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 1
        dateAdded   nullable: true,  blank: false
    }
}
```

The query that IntelliJ logs to the console when Wallpaper.list() has been called (this query actually works when I copy-paste it in the MySQL editor and run it: records are returned).

```
select wallpaper0_.id as id1_4_, wallpaper0_.date_added as date_add2_4_, wallpaper0_.width as width3_4_, wallpaper0_.height as height4_4_, wallpaper0_.favourite as favourit5_4_, wallpaper0_.location as location6_4_, wallpaper0_.high_quality as high_qua7_4_, wallpaper0_.description as descript8_4_, wallpaper0_.purity as purity9_4_ from wallpaper wallpaper0_
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with the Wallpaper domain class (or anything else, if the domain class turns out to be correct)?

Things I have tried:

- Add a schema name to the domain class.

What I expected to happen:

- Data should be returned when Wallpaper.list() is called.

What actually resulted:

- No data was returned when Wallpaper.list() was called.

Comment: Do other queries like `Wallpaper.findAll()` work? Did you check the database connection settings to confirm if it's connecting to the right database?

Comment: @PuneetBehl The Wallpaper.findAll() query did not work and the project has been connect to the correct database (In IntelliJ, when I go to the Database tab on the right hand side > Data Sources and Drivers (wrench icon) > Schemas (tab) it has my database schema as the 'current schema' (I'm assuming it's connected to the correct one when that's stated).

Comment: What I wanted to verify is that application is connecting to the correct database? but connecting to DB via IntelliJ does not tell anything. It appears that the application configuration and driver setting are wrong which need to updated.

Comment: @PuneetBehl Apparently I was not connecting to a database at all. I thought no further configuration was required, but I still had to adjust settings in the application.yml file. I have posted an answer a few days ago underneath with my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was not completely in the domain class, but apparently I was using the wrong connector, application.yml and build.gradle settings.

For people who are also having trouble, the things I have changed are listed below:

BUILD.GRADLE > dependencies:

- Changed "runtimeOnly **com.h2database:h2**" to "runtimeOnly **mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.12**".

APPLICATION.YML > environments.development.datasource:

- Set "driverClassName" to value "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver".
- Set "url" to value "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jws" ('jws' being the schema name).
- Set "dbCreate" to value "validate" (makes sure to check if the domain classes are configured correctly and respond with errors if any have been found).
- Set the "username" and "password" values to my database username and password (in application.yml, this was set to username "sa" and the password was left blank by default).

If you have any further questions, please ask: maybe I (or somebody else) can be of assistance.